# How to scrape on two different domain using scrapy?

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy

Hi I would like to scrape 2 different domain in my script I have tried my if statement but I it seems that it is not working, any idea please?

Here's my code

```
class SalesitemSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'salesitem_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www2.hm.com']
    start_urls = [
         'https://www2.hm.com/en_us/sale/shopbyproductladies/view-all.html?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=stillLife&offset=0&page-size=9999',
         'https://www.forever21.com/us/shop/catalog/category/f21/sale',
     ]

    def parse_start_url(response):
        if (response.url == 'https://www2.hm.com/en_us/sale/shopbyproductladies/view-all.html?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=stillLife&offset=0&page-size=9999'):
            parse_1(response)
        if (response.url == 'https://www.forever21.com/us/shop/catalog/category/f21/sale'):
            parse_2(response)

    def parse_1(self, response):
        for product_item in response.css('li.product-item'):
            item = {
                'title': product_item.css('h3.item-heading a.link::text').extract_first(),
                'regular-price': product_item.css('strong.item-price span.price.regular::text').extract_first(),
                'sale-price': product_item.css('strong.item-price span.price.sale::text').extract_first(),
                'photo-url': product_item.css('.image-container img::attr(data-src)').extract_first(),
                'description-url': "https://www2.hm.com/" + product_item.css('h3.item-heading a::attr(href)').extract_first(),
            }
            yield item

    def parse_2(self, response):
        #Some code getting item on domain 2
```

Please Help thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check your `allowed_domains` variable. You should add new domain, like `['www2.hm.com', 'forever21.com']` or remove it at all. Also you have no `parse` function.

I can suppose to remove your `start_urls` with `if` and use `start_requests` instead. Your code will be more readable.

```
import scrapy


class SalesitemSpiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'salesitem_spider'
    allowed_domains = ['www2.hm.com', 'forever21.com']

    def start_requests(self):
        urls = (
            (self.parse_1, 'https://www2.hm.com/en_us/sale/shopbyproductladies/view-all.html?sort=stock&image-size=small&image=stillLife&offset=0&page-size=9999'),
            (self.parse_2, 'https://www.forever21.com/us/shop/catalog/category/f21/sale'),
        )
        for cb, url in urls:
            yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=cb)

    def parse_1(self, response):
        print 111111111

    def parse_2(self, response):
        print 2222222222
```

Comment: Thank you @vezunchik, i've tried your given code but I've got an error "Error while obtaining start requests" and "AttributeError: 'SalesitemSpiderSpider' object has no attribute 'parse_1'"

Comment: Did you copy your `parse_1` and `parse_2` function to class? I've updated typo in urls, check code now.